# When using Data Migration tool I get exception undefined index

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, error, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I've successfully installed Data migration tool.

I have a magento 1.9.1.0 and magento 2.1.3 runing locally on MAMP under OSX Sierra.

The magento 1 is running under htdocs/magento1 and magento 2 is running in htdocs/magento2, so I access to them with localhost:8888/magento1 and localhost:8888/magento2.

The database name in magento1 is `hello` and the database name in magento 2 is `hello-test`, none of them use prefixes.

When I try to do a migration from magento 1 to magento 2 I get an error:

```
[Exception] Notice: Undefined index: name in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/ResourceModel/Adapter/Pdo/MysqlBuilder.php on line 82
```

The configxml that I configured is:

```
<source>
    <database host="localhost:8888/magento1/" user="root" password="1234"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="localhost/magento2/" user="root" password="1234"/>
</destination>
<options>
    <crypt_key><![CDATA[abcd1234]]></crypt_key>
</options>
```

And the command I use to init the migration is:

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/ce-to-ce/1.9.1.0/config.xml
```

What can be failing? I've been searching in google for a while but I find nothing...

Edit: I passed the xml in a xml validator and I see some errors:

this line `<database host="localhost:8888/magento1/" user="root" password="1234"/>` 
display the error `cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'name' must appear on element 'database'.`

this line `<database host="localhost:8888/magento2/" user="root" password="1234"/>`
display the error `cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'name' must appear on element 'database'.`

and this xml reference to `../../config.xsd` and this file displays the error `InvalidRegex: Pattern value '[-/A-Za-z0-9\._]+\.(xml|dist)' is not a valid regular expression. The reported error was: ''-' is an invalid character range. Write '\-'.'.` 
on this line `<xs:restriction base="xs:string">`

edit 2:
if change the config.xml to

```
<source>
    <database host="127.0.0.1:8888/magento1/" name="hello" user="root" password="1234"/>
</source>
<destination>
    <database host="127.0.0.1:8888/magento2/" name="hello-test" user="root" password="1234"/>
</destination>
```

then the error is:

```
  [Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory  

  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I'm going to explain it here because maybe in the future it helps somebody:

1.- enter in the magento 2 folder.

2.- type in terminal `php -i | grep 'php.ini'`

3.- if you get

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini
```

then it is failing because of that, you are using php from OSX and not from MAMP

4.- edit `~/.profile` (ie. open Terminal and type `nano ~/.profile`)

5.- add this line to the end of the file

`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/bin/:$PATH`

The x of php is the version number, in my case i'm using 5.6.38 so I added

`export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.38/bin/:$PATH`

6.- restart computer

7.- now, if you type in terminal `php -i | grep 'php.ini'` you should get something like this

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.28/conf
Loaded Configuration File => /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.28/conf/php.ini
```

Now when you try to import it should work.

Comment: hey, facing the issue on Ubuntu now, can you help me on what should be the export path?

Answer (score 0):

Install a sane development environment first:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/optimal-dev-environment.html

Then follow the data migration docs:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/migration-tool.html

I.e.: I don't see the encryption key wrapped in cdata there.

But your actual error is that you forgot to put the database name as in:

```
<database host="127.0.0.1" name="magento1" user="root"/>
```

Comment: I already read and followed the migration tool guides, the encryption key in a cdata or without cdata doesn't change anything.
I enabled the developer mode in magento 2, now I get the error '[Migration\Exception] XML file is invalid.' instead the error I got before.

Comment: Well according to the error it doesn't find the index `name` wherever it is looking for it. I suspect you either missed a configuration step or misconfigured. If you get an XML invalid error that might likely be the cause. Try checking the xml in an online validator. You probably put illegal characters.

Comment: I passed a xml validator and updated the question with the result, the config.xsd that gives an invalid character error remains untouched since the installation

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: I removed the names before because I understood in the documentation that the name is required only if you use the prefix magento1 in the database, and I'm not using any prefix. If I write the dataase names here the error changes to `[Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception]                       
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` and `[PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`